# accdr runtime error, missing references?

Tags: ms-access, vba

so I have an access 2010 application and am trying to run it on a pc with just MS office and access 2010 runtime installed. when I open the accdr file on the other pc, I get a runtime error as soon as it opens up and then I click ok and then it closes. I've tried the accdr file on my pc and it works fine. I'm guess the other PC has some missing references and thats whats causing it? How do I check to see what references are missing on the other pc?

Answer (score 1):

Since the other computer has MS Office installed you can do the following:

1. Make note of the references in your full version of MS Access
2. Open Excel on the other computer
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA
4. Go to Tools --> References...
5. Attempt to find the references you noted in the first step above

Any references you are unable to find in Excel VBA will also not be available in the Access runtime.

Comment: so in excel I'll see the same ones as I do in access? I did find some on my side that was not on the other pc, how can I install the ones that are not on the list?

Comment: The References dialog is a generic VBA dialog, so it will be the same whether you are looking at it from Excel or Access (or Word or Outlook, etc.)  With regard to installing missing references, that depends entirely on which ones are not on the list.  If you post the names of the missing references we may be able to point you in the right direction.  Also, keep in mind there may be licensing considerations that restrict distribution of the missing libraries.

Comment: I'm seeing "ctv OLE Control module", "Microsoft forms 2.0 Object Library", "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)", "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library", "Microsoft AtiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library"